# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed

Tags: java, javamail

Я пытаюсь подключиться к почтовому серверу Exchange с общей электронной почтой и у меня произошла вылетая ошибка javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed. Если я использую общую электронную почту без чисел в имени, соединение работает.

- 7777@dc1.local - не работает
- twsg@dc1.local - работает

Мои проперти для подключения:

```
mail.imap.starttls.enable=true, 
mail.imap.timeout=30000, 
mail.imap.host=192.168.112.211, 
mail.imap.port=993, 
mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory.fallback=false, 
mail.imap.connectiontimeout=30000, 
mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable=true, 
mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory=com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory@3932399c, 
mail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true, 
mail.imap.ssl.enable=true, 
mail.imap.starttls.required=true, 
mail.imap.partialfetch=false
```

Стек ошибки:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: require STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect returning false, host=192.168.112.211, user=iziunin, password=<null>
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "192.168.112.211", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
D0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
D0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=192.168.112.211, user=vpsd@dc1.local\7777@dc1.local, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism NTLM disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable
D1 LOGIN "vpsd@dc1.local\\7777@dc1.local" **********
D1 NO LOGIN failed.
236661 [ValidateInboundMailServerConfigAction(2e63eede-1bde-4e03-957b-304ca7a4e60b) naumen #213 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 connection-validator] (04 июн. 2020 16:53:20,175) ERROR mail.ConnectionValidationService - LOGIN failed. [a758bfcc6975a101/a758bfcc6975a101/5e6332efdc99a195] 
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at ru.naumen.mailreader.server.receiver.MailReceiverImplBase.doConnect(MailReceiverImplBase.java:275)
    at ru.naumen.mailreader.server.receiver.MailReceiverImplBase.connect(MailReceiverImplBase.java:143)
```

Comment: У почты выключен Открытый доступ?

Comment: @merive_ Да, включен открытый доступ

Comment: `vpsd@dc1.local\7777@dc1.local` разве корректный username? Не должно быть `dc1.local\7777` либо `7777@dc1.local` ? https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#Exchange-login

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом нужно понять где проблема: на стороне клиента или сервера.
Пробуем вот эту софтину:

https://github.com/manusa/mnIMAPSync

У меня коннектится к Exchange без проблем. Если не коннектится, значит что-то не так с Exchange.

Попробуйте подключится к обычной почте Вашим кодом. Если ..., ну, понятно.

Ещё момент, рекомендую использовать вот эти компоненты для тестирования с Exchange:

https://www.example-code.com/java/imap.asp

Ещё есть крайне маленькая вероятность, что Вы используете настолько древние версии, что сказываются нюансы в версия протокола IMAP, но это стоит проверять в последнюю очередь.